# How to stop "Ignoring query projection" warning for LOCAL Ignite cache

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I'm running a `ScanQuery` on an Ignite cluster that is currently only a local cache.  Every time it runs, I am getting a warning message below:

> WARN  Ignoring query projection because it's executed over LOCAL cache (only local node will be queried): GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=com.sms.ignite.IgniteUtils$1@10895ea7, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=o.a.i.i.cluster.ClusterGroupAdapter@5307bf01, keepBinary=false, subjId=null, taskHash=0]

I've done some research and saw on the Ignite forums that this issue has been seen before, but haven't found any fix.  Is there any sort of logging setting or configuration that will keep me from getting spammed with this message? I am fully aware that the cache is local, and don't want my entire log filling up with this useless message.

Comment: What kind of queries are you going to issue against your local cache?

Comment: A ScanQuery to find all the objects in the cache that meet certain criteria--checking the value of one of the fields of the object that isn't part of the key for the cache.

Comment: Why don't you use a Java HashMap for that? I'm asking since Ignite community is planning to discontinue LOCAL caches with 3.0 release (next year).

Comment: Long term we plan to expand to two servers--but at that point the cache won't be local anymore, so the warning will go away I assume.  In the meantime, we need the data structure to be searchable with SQL parameters, so a HashMap wouldn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider upgrade. I don't think this warning exists in `2.7.5`.